# Which factors determine the appropriate value for settingsFork in a Warp application?

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-warp

In [Warp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.0.13.1) applications, the `settingsFork` option is available on the [Settings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.0.13.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp-Internal.html#t:Settings) data type. This allows one to choose a different fork model. When should this be set to something other than the default (`void . forkIOWithUnmask`)? Which factors should be taken into account when making this decision? (IO vs CPU bound/use of FFI, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [`forkOS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkOS) to create a bound thread if you're going to be manipulating thread-local state (as unbound Haskell "threads" might run on different OS threads, and therefore ruin the whole idea of using thread-local storage in the first place). The documentation mentions OpenGL as a possible example. Overall though, I find it difficult to come up with a situation where you wouldn't want the default implementation, which takes advantage of the builtin green-thread system. It's received wisdom that GHC's scheduler is [hard to beat](http://www.aosabook.org/en/posa/warp.html).